# OnClick/Onhover Javascript/jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

Any ideas on how to create a **Onclick/Hover** event that would show a caption/bubble/popup that i would want to use as a quick help button. would appreciate any ideas or redirects on other sources/articles.

Edit: This is what i got so far.

```
    $(document).ready(function()
 {
    $('a[title]').qtip();
 });


  <div class="helpcss"><a href="" title="HELP HELP HELP HELP">Help?</a></div>
```

Asking is there any good ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/)

Comment: @jprofitt looked into it too already made it running. Thanks anyway just asking other people what are better options. Too bad they like to down vote instead of showing some idea. =)

Comment: We like to downvote because your question is in no way properly formed. We'd like to see some code/effort on your part. We're not a codie-it-for-you website :) Help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="myPopup" style="display: hidden;">Hey here's your help<div>
<a href="" id="myLink">Click me</a>
```

```
$.on("hover", "#myLink", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#myPopup").show();
});
$("#myLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myPopup").show();
});
```

This is rough, and might get you started. There are a bajillion tutorials on the internet, maybe a bit more googling will produce something useful.

Comment: Thanks, This is great help i will try this, I actually found some and its Jquery i will try to compare which is better.

Comment: @Tony ... actually the code provided here **IS** jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers, if you set the title attribute of the link or input, there will be a tool tip when the user hover over the element.

That is the fastest way.